# My SQL code works In phpMyAdmin SQL feature but shows an error in Events

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've been building a database for a website. I want to create an Event in which my ID will reset after deleting some rows (Different Event).

The code works fine when I use it in SQL but shows an error when I put the same code in an Event. It's a syntax error near `UPDATE`.

This is the code:

```
SET @count = 0; UPDATE `Work` SET `id` = @count:= @count + 1;
```

Comment: it's possible that the command terminator is not semi-colon (;) in the Event, have you checked that?

Comment: Are you talking about a DELETE trigger?  If so:Restrictions

You can not create an AFTER trigger on a view.
You can not update the NEW values.
You can not update the OLD values.